# How can I get my session id working

Tags: php, sql, session

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
      $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
      header('location: index.php');
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    }
  }
```

Help me that how can I echo that my session is working or not and how my session is working.

Comment: you can use `if(isset($_SESSION["id"])){//do something}`. This is basic knowledge in PHP, you shouldn't ask here, instead, read it from php.net

Comment: where i have to put this code

Comment: presumably th escript begins with `session_start();`??

Comment: session is already started above

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
switch (session_status())
{
    case PHP_SESSION_NONE|1: echo 'NONE'; 
        session_start ([$_SESSION['id'] = 25, $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in"]); 
        break;
    case PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE|2: echo 'ACTIVE';
        if(isset(~)) {~}
        break;
}
```

Comment: The quality of your answer will be greatly increased if you explain your solution.  This will also help new users and future searches.  Ex. why do you use `(~)` or `{~}`.

Comment: I agree with @Nic3500 here. This seems like a "HOT ROD" solution and if there was a reasonable explanation to back it up, it would probably make for a great answer. Not just the tilde `~` but the `|` also. If you cannot give a proper explanation as to why they should use this, then the answer would be of very low-quality.